# Proving equality with a norm of a linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I got help on the previous parts of this question but I'm at a loss about where to go from here. I can prove the linear functional is bounded and that the norm is less than two but this last part I am stuck on and the hint isn't helping me. Any help would be really appreciated.

[image]